# mongoose plugin $set with concat on save

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to write a simple mongoose plugin that will replace the `delete` function to do kind of soft-delete. It will set a `deleted` flag but also renames properties which are unique. For example the property `name` is unique `name = 'My Company'`, on delete it should be set to `'My Company_deleted'` (of course it will be a bit more advanced). My idea was to use the `$concat` operator but no idea how to place it correctly.

This is what I tried in the plugin function (here hardcoded the property `name`):

```
schema.methods.delete = async function () {
  this.deleted = true;

  this.$set = { name: { $concat: [ "$name", "_deleted" ] } };
    
  return this.save();
};
```

This obviously gives a `CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ '$concat': [ '$name', '_deleted' ] }" (type Object) at path "name"`.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$set` is the `$set` property of your Model, which is not correct.

You might just want to do this with simple string manipulation.

```
schema.methods.delete = async function () {
  this.deleted = true;
  this.name = `${this.name}_deleted`

  return this.save();
};
```

Otherwise, if you were doing this with an update statement instead of a custom model method, you could do

```
CompanyModel.updateOne(
   {_id: id}, 
   {$set: {
      deleted: true, 
      name: {$concat: ["$name", "_deleted"]}
   }}
)
```

Where `{_id: id}` is the filter to what document you want to do, and the second object is the updates you want to perform to the matching document.